# Resize of the main view in interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I try to follow by tutorial but this is quite old tutorial and here some issue when you run the app with the view of the app.

[image]

There is no images and I rebuild constraints but nothing has changed.

Code of the ViewController:

```
class MasterViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
  @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
    }
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
      self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath, animated: true)
    }
  }
}

extension MasterViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  }

}

extension MasterViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

  func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
  }

}
```

How can I resize it not just for iPhone 4 (or get rid of black areas)?

Comment: show your code, please

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade, Done!

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade Get rid of black areas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the appropriate launch images inside **Images.xcassets > LaunchImage** for the resolutions that you want to support. For example, for iPhone 5 portrait, the resolution would be 640x1136.

Here is a screenshot of the interface to look for in Xcode:

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, follow the below steps:

1. Navigate to project settings
2. Under "App Icons and Launch Images" click on "Use Asset Catalog"
3. Select "Migrate" on the popup that appears.

This should fix the issue.